# Can not remove the item from list using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a chat app when i want to delete the chat which i do with my friend but the chat cannot deleted from the fire-base but at the same time also create the duplicate value in fire-base which i want to delete from chat list .I can't understand which method call which do this .some time its work but mostly it duplicate this. i try almost all the solutions but didn't work properly what i can do now ???`enter code here`

```
holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mycontex, v);
                    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.del_job:

                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(mycontex);
                                    builder1.setMessage("Are you sure to delete your chat?");
                                    builder1.setCancelable(true);

                                    builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                            "Yes",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                                    mConvDatabase.child(list_id).setValue(null);
                                                    mMessageDatabase.child(list_id).setValue(null);

                                                    mFirebaseAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

                                                    Toast.makeText(mycontex, "sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                }
                                            });

                                    builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                            "No",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                    dialog.cancel();

                                                }
                                            });

                                    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                    alert11.show();

                                    return true;

                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delchat_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
                    popupMenu.show();

                    return true;
                }
            });



        }
    };

    mConvList.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
    mFirebaseAdapter.startListening();
```

}

Comment: Try to use `remove()` instead of setting value `null`

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman In the Firebase Real Time Database setting a value to null, nil or "" will remove that node. A node cannot exist without a value.

Comment: @jay yes you are right  but when i both try this at the same time duplicate node generated

Comment: any one have any  solution  @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: Add your database structure and reference code